# Ui календарь, убрать выбранную дату при повторном клике

Tags: jquery-ui, javascript, ui

Доброго времени суток всем.

Есть обычный ui календарь:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    monthNames: monthNames,
    dayNamesMin: dayNamesMin,
    firstDay: 1,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('.for-datepicker-section').val(dateText);
    }
});
```

При выборе даты в поле вписывается значение. Вопрос: как убирать выбранную дату при повторном клике на неё? Пробовал в onSelect делать проверку и убирать классы у таблицы календаря, но не получилось. Помогите, плиз, кто знает.

Comment: @Karalahti, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
  if($('.for-datepicker-section').val() == dateText){ // Предыдущая дата та же что и выбранная
    $('.for-datepicker-section').val('');
  }else{
    $('.for-datepicker-section').val(dateText);
  }
}
```